# Grails: Edit and Delete links not working

Tags: grails, groovy, filter

I created an extra column and added icons at the end of the list for editing and deleting an event.

Here is what I have

```
<g:form value="${it.id}">
                            <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${it.id}" />
                            <span class="simple"><g:actionSubmit class="editar" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.editar.label', default: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')}" /></span>
                            <span class="simple"><g:actionSubmit class="eliminar" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.eliminar.label', default: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Esta seguro que desea Eliminar?')}');" /></span>
                        </g:form>
```

I wrote `The ID is ${it.id}` and it recognizes it and gives me the ID number, so I don't know where the problem is. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

So I figured the mistake was in the controller where edit and delete are defined

```
def edit = {
    def entryInstance = Entry.get(params.id)
    if (!entryInstance) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'entry.label', default: 'Proyecto/Ruta'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    else {
        return [entryInstance: entryInstance]
    }
}
```

I think since it says params.id in the get parameters I not working right, what other alternatives do I have??

Comment: Hey Fernando, can you describe what's happening exactly?  You populate the results, click on the 'edit' or 'delete' button, then what?

Comment: then it goes to edit.gsp or delete.gsp respectively...

Comment: updated the post because i think the mistake is in the controller

Comment: Wait... you click on edit and it goes to edit.gsp?  Isn't it doing what you want it to do?

Comment: if I click it from list.gsp yes it does, but when I click it from the filtered resulter in searchResults.gsp it throws me an error saying can't find the id, and what's posted up there is from searchResults.gsp, the code works fine in list.gsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<g:form id="${it.id}"> 
   <span class="simple">
     <g:actionSubmit class="editar" action="edit" 
                     value="${message(code:'default.button.editar.label', 
                                      default: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')}" />
   </span>
   <span class="simple">
     <g:actionSubmit class="eliminar" action="delete" 
                     value="${message(code: 'default.button.eliminar.label', 
                                      default: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')}" 
                     onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Esta seguro que desea Eliminar?')}');" />
   </span>
 </g:form>
```

In summary: replace the value="${it.id}" in your g:form tag with id="{it.id}" and remove the hiddenField for ID. I think that will correct the problem.

Let me know if it doesn't work...

Comment: Now I am missing one last thing, that it loads the automatic filter when the page first opens. I will post a new question and some more code tomorrow morning. you've been of great help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Here is the link to the new question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150155/grails-how-do-i-make-my-page-load-a-filter-when-the-page-loads